# Unmanaged DLL in C# not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, c, dll, opencv

I've been working on DLL which uses OpenCV to do some tracking. Got everything working on a C console project using VS 2008 (for testing purposes). Then I made a new DLL project and got it compiled. I setted up everything so I just had put a single function on a `Thread` Class to call a single function.

Then I created a C# project for GUI and other stuff. The DLL loads fine (using `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, the method starts (I can see the capture window created by OpenCV) but the tracking is not being done. To verify the DLL was actually working, I loaded on Python and called the method and it ran fine (tracking was being made).

I'm new to working with unmanaged DLL's on managed code. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong or how can I debug this? If you need anything else to help me solve this problem I'll provide it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I'm not using a class on the DLL, I'm using a single function, the Thread class comes from the `System.Threading` on C#

The way I'm using the DLL is like this.

```
namespace GUI
{
    static class NativeTracking
    {
        [DllImport(@"__Tracking.dll")]
        public static extern void _Tracking();
    }
}
```

The I put it on a thread like his

```
public GUI()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _tracking = new Thread(_Tracking);
    _tracking.Start();
}

public _Tracking()
{
    while(True)
    {
        NativeTracking.Tracking();
    }
}
```

Edit: Native Coded

Native Code, sorry for the messy format.

Header File

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "..\original\project\myheader.h"
#include "..\original\project\myheader1.h"
#include "..\original\project\myheader2.h"
#include "..\original\project\myheader3.h"
#include "..\original\project\myheader4.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

    _declspec(dllexport) void Tracking();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Implementation

```
#include "exposed.h"

void Tracking( )
{
int flag = 1, i=0;
iplImgs imgs;
trackingTool tools;
helperTools helperTools;

CvCapture* capture = 0;
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 20.0f);

imgs.image = 0;

    cvNamedWindow( "Window", 0 );
initHelperTools(&helperTools);
initTools(&imgs, &tools);

    for(;;){

    int c;
            IplImage* frame = 0;

    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );        
    if( !frame )
        break;

    if( !imgs.image ){
            /* allocate all the buffers */
            prepareImages(&imgs, &tools, frame);
        }

        cvCopy( frame, imgs.image, 0 );
        cvCvtColor( imgs.image, imgs.grey, CV_BGR2GRAY );

        if( flag == 1 || conditionB ){
        someOperations(&imgs, &tools);
        if (conditionC)
            flag = 0;
        }
    else if( conditionD ){
        otherOps(&helperTools, imgs.grey);
        someTrack(&imgs, &tools, &helperTools, drawPoints);
        someCorrections(&tools);
        if ( condition ){
            if (!wasReset){
                wasReset = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if ( validation )
            someMoreOperations(&tools, corretions);
        }
    }   

    bufferHandlingOps(&imgs);


        c = cvWaitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 )
            break;
    switch ((char)c){
        case 'p':
            drawPoints ^= 1;
            break;
        default:
            ;
    }
    }

    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow("Window");
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have classes, so either you don't have a thread class, or you aren't using C.

Comment: I'm not using a class on the DLL, I'm using a single function, the Thread class comes from the `System.Threading` on C#.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your native "Tracking" method?

Answer (score 3):

One problem I see is that you're using the default C calling convention in your native code, which is "[*_*_cdecl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl)", and in your P/Invoke "DLLImport" attribute you're letting it use the default calling for C# which is "[__stdcall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall)". This is probably throwing a run time exception whenever you invoke your native method.

Also, I realize that you're not passing any arguments or expecting any results, but the calling convention does denote the way the function is decorated, which can lead to [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) problems.
You can:

1. Change your native export to "__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Tracking();"
2. Or change the "[CallingConvention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx)" property on your DLLImport attribute: [DllImport(@"__Tracking.dll") CallingConvention = CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl]

Comment: Hi, I tried this, coded ended like this `__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Tracking();` if I changed this order DLL won't compile `[DllImport(@"CamComtrolDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]` If I use `CallingConvention.Cdelc` I got `EntryPointNotFound` Exception. DLL is supposed to be a black box, No input received and output direct to the system, but it can be modified to return some values and handled on the managed source

Comment: @Loki You're right, that was a typo in my example and I fixed it. The calling convention must come between the return type and method name. The important thing is that both are using the same calling convention, so only make one of the changes I suggested, not both or it'll be the same as you have now. I also realize that it's a black box routine and the calling convention is used for balancing the stack with function arguments, however I mentioned it because of the possible name mangling. I also creating a sample project that is setup exactly like yours (minus the opencv stuff obviously)

Comment: and I'm not having any problems, everything is working as expected. Have you tried executing it without creating a new thread just to narrow down the possible causes for errors ?

Answer (score 2):

One of the problem of DllImport (P/Invoke) is that is not type safe. You knows it's working only runtime because you don't have a way to check it at compile time if:

- the signature of the method is the right one;
- the mangling of the method is correct.

It's very popular for WIN32 methods because you'll find plenty of examples that work, but for the lib you are using, it's a matter of trying and trying until it works or you find the specific problem that's blocking you (remember to verify the dll is in the same directory, or in system directory, of the executable when it runs).

My advice is to create a proper wrapper in C++/CLI. It doesn't have the problems above and it's esier to debug in case of problems. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318842/how-to-wrap-c-library-callbacks-in-c-cli/5318861#5318861) is a more complex example I wrote in the case of a callback in C to expose in C#.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of C++/CLI wrapper.  This seems like the easiest way to start figuring out this problem.